# How to integrate $x^2\sin(x^2)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int x^2\sin(x^2)dx$$
Methods I know of: Reversing the chain, substitution, parts. Any help greatly appreciated.

Edit: Note that the integral is not $x^2\ast(\sin x)^2$

Comment: Parts first.  you won't be able to get a direct integral of $\sin(x^2)$, but you can take its derivative, so set that as the $u$ in $\int udv$. --- even then that won't be enough, it looks like this requires the Fresnel integrals anyway.

Comment: But you are still faced with needing one of the Fresnel integrals (which are well-known but not elementary functions).

Comment: I haven't come across that method before. I'm only in year 12 and my maths teacher set it as a challenge.

Comment: Are you sure it is $\;\sin(x^2)\;$ and not $\;\sin^2x=(\sin x)^2\;$ ?

Comment: Yes it is sin(x^2) not (sin(x))^2 = sin^2(x)

Comment: You just get recurrence nothing more. I think

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid that this is one integral where there is no nice form for the antiderivative. There are many ways to estimate the antiderivative. The simplest is to use the power series representation of $\sin(x)$.

The Maclaurin series for $\sin(x)$ was known as far back as the 14th century by  Madhava of Sangamagrama. This series is often covered about halfway through a Calculus 2 course. It is given by $$\sin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1}=x-\frac{1}{3!}x^3+\frac{1}{5!}x^5-\frac{1}{7!}x^7+\cdots.$$

Replacing $x^2$ for $x$ gives:

$$\sin(x^2) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{4n+2}$$

and multiplying by $x^2$ gives:

$$x^2 \sin(x^2) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{4n+4}.$$

Now if we want to antidifferentiate this quantity we find:

$$\int x^2 \sin(x^2) dx = C+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(4n+5)(2n+1)!} x^{4n+5}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the response, however I'm only 16 (year 12) and my maths teacher set this as a challenge based on my current knowledge(parts l, sub, reversing the chain rule). Hence there must be another way.

Comment: Note that $\int x^2 \sin^2 x dx$ would be integrable using what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Fresnel's integrals are defined as:

$S(x) = \int\limits_{0}^{x} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\alpha^2\right) ~ d\alpha$

$C(x) = \int\limits_{0}^{x} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\alpha^2\right) ~ d\alpha$

Sometimes the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is left out, but I chose to include it.

If you are a student in high school calculus, you should have learned the second fundamental theorem, which states that if $F(x)$ can be defined as
$$F(x) = \int\limits_{c}^{x} f(\alpha) ~ d\alpha$$

Then $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$.

Perhaps your teacher wanted you to realize that the integral is not expressible by elementary functions, and define a new function (namely the Fresnel functions) using the fundamental theorem to solve it. You don't need to have been previously aware of the Fresnel integral to do this. It is also possible that your teacher assigned this knowing you cannot do it, so that they can later make the point that integration is much harder than differentiation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However I am unsure that the teacher set it knowing I would be unable to complete it. Can this not be done in any way by reversing the chain rule or by parts?

Comment: Unless you define a new function, there is no way to solve it using what you know.

Comment: I am 99% sure that this can be solved using what I know. I am not doubting your knowledge, it is just when they set challenges they are do-able.

Comment: @John: This one isn't, 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to prove that this integral comes down to the non-elementary Fresnel integral: integrate by parts.  Taking $u=x, dv=x\sin(x^2) dx$ we have
$du=dx$ (trivially) and $v=\int x\sin(x^2) dx = -\frac12\cos(x^2)$, so we get
$$\int x^2\sin(x^2)\ dx = \int x\cdot x\sin(x^2)\ dx = -\frac12x\cos(x^2)+\int\frac12\cos(x^2)\ dx$$

Since we've found a relation in terms of elementary functions between $\int x^2\sin(x^2)\ dx$ and $\int \cos(x^2)\ dx$, then if one were expressible in terms of elementary functions then the other would have to be; but it is widely known (as other answers have mentioned) that $\int \cos(x^2)\ dx$ cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions, so neither can $\int x^2\sin(x^2)\ dx$.

Comment: Is the integral of xsin(x^2) not -1/2 * cos(x^2)

Comment: Whoops - yes, it is. Fixed, though of course that doesn't materially affect the result here.